# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'librosa' with python programming language

Tags: python, librosa

I am using python programming language and Installed librosa version 0.8 on windows 10 operating system and installed successfully but when import library it gives me error ----> "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'librosa'"

I tried solution from below articles but failed
https://nomodulenamed.com/m/librosa
https://pypi.org/project/librosa/

appreciate if someone faced same issue

Comment: How did you install the package, and how are you attempting to use it? Are you sure the interpreter that you installed it with and the interpreter that you are using now are the same?

Comment: We need more information.  Are you running from a command line, or inside VSCode, or in Jupyter, or in PyCharm, or what?  The problem is that you have multiple versions of Python, and you have installed it into one that is not the one you're using.

Comment: Double check the location of your installation. Is it in the same library directory as your application?

Comment: if you install package, check the PYTHONPATH for that.

Comment: which version of python are you using?

Comment: @Brian I installed it using pip install librosa , yes I am sure that it is installed with same interpreter version

Comment: @TimRoberts I installed from cmd in windows 10, I have only one version of python 3.9.1

Comment: @Parzival python 3.9.1

Comment: @Nilesh Python path    C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\

Comment: Please try `python -m pip install librosa` and edit the question to show the results.

Comment: @Hesham please update your question which what you tried and how.

Answer (score 0):

After installing, in the command prompt, print the version of librosa, using `pip show librosa`

If the information is displayed, it means that you have successfully installed librosa. However, if the error still persists it's (most likely) because of 1 of 3 reasons:

1. Your files aren't in the same directory as your libraries, or
2. You need to restart your kernel to allow it to access the library.
3. Librosa only works with 3.7.9 and earlier, so you might be using an incompatible version of python.

Because you are using 3.9.1, it is probably caused because of the 3rd reason.